# Where condition inside of an aggregate?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to return the first and last inventory transaction date for every item# in my item master table from the inventory transaction table. I need the last date to show if there's been recent activity of any kind, but I need the first date for the purpose of showing when the part was created. There is a transaction code description for this = 'NEW ITEM' so I want to filter the minimum date aggregation for this code, but I don't want any filter on the max date aggregation. The transaction table is millions of rows.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this than just two CTE subqueries?

```
WITH MinDate AS(
SELECT
PartID
,MIN(TransDate) AS 'MinTrans'
FROM Translog
WHERE TransDesc = 'NEW ITEM'
GROUP BY PartID),
MaxDate AS(
SELECT
PartID
,MAX(TransDate) AS 'MaxTrans'
FROM Translog
GROUP BY PartID)

SELECT
PartID
,MinTrans
,MaxTrans
FROM ItemTab
LEFT JOIN MinDate 
ON MinDate.PartID = ItemTab.PartID
LEFT JOIN MaxDate
ON MaxDate.PartID = ItemTab.PartID
```

Comment: If your grouping has different condition, then no.

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read. Proper indentation would make it easier to assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called a **Conditional Aggregation**.   Note the case expression within the `min()`

**Example**

```
Select  PartID
       ,MinTrans = min( case when TransDesc = 'NEW ITEM' then TransDate end)
       ,MaxTrans = max( TransDate )
From  Translog
Group By  PartID
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks for your help!

Do you know if this is actually more performant than using multiple CTEs? It seems like it ought to be, but coding for performance is not my specialty.

Comment: @funkyman50 I would suspect it is.

Comment: @funkyman50 check the execution plan of each and see